# SignlaR authentication - handle unauthorized

Tags: javascript, c#, authorization, signalr, signalr.client

So after following this article, 
http://www.asp.net/signalr/overview/security/hub-authorization

I could not find anything about how to inform somehow the user that he is not authorized.

In the System.Web.Mvc.AuthorizeAttribute you can have

```
protected override void HandleUnauthorizedRequest(AuthorizationContext filterContext)
{
   ...
}
```

where you can handle the request and redirect the user to a page.

I understand that in SignlaR's case it is a websocket request and you cannot redirect.

But is there a way to handle the 401 unauthorized response from JavaScript, to at least display a message?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can handle SignalR disconnection reason in JavaScript. See [Understanding and Handling Connection Lifetime Events in SignalR](http://www.asp.net/signalr/overview/guide-to-the-api/handling-connection-lifetime-events).

```
$.connection.hub.disconnected(function () {
    if ($.connection.hub.lastError) 
        { alert("Disconnected. Reason: " +  $.connection.hub.lastError.message); }
});
```